# "Arduino Alarm System with DS3231 RTC: Display RTC Values and Access Menu System"

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am beginer in programming and now already working on arduino based  Alarm System with the DS3231 RTC module.I want to display my current rtc value on lcd display and when pressing the i want to acess my menu system for setup the rtc and other things.with following code, its does not work,when pressing the "BTN ACCEPT" according to the code it just showing menu and continue to displayRTCValues function.this is my code in loop.i can provide complete code.

```
void loop() {
  t = rtc.getTime();// print the current time on display
  Day = rtc.getDOWStr(1);//Print the name of the day on display

  hh = t.hour,DEC;
  mm = t.min,DEC;
  ss = t.sec,DEC;
  dd = t.date,DEC;
  bb = t.mon,DEC;
  yy = t.year,DEC;

      // Display the current RTC values on the LCD
    displayRTCValues();
  

    // Check if the accept button is pressed to access the root menu
    if (btnIsUp(BTN_ACCEPT) && !btn_Accept_WasDown) {
        // Wait until the accept button is released to avoid multiple presses
        while (btnIsUp(BTN_ACCEPT)) {
            delay(50);
        }

        // Set CurrentPage to ROOT_MENU to show the root menu
        CurrentPage = ROOT_MENU;

        // Clear the LCD display (optional)
        lcd.clear();
    }

    // Call the appropriate function based on the CurrentPage value
    switch (CurrentPage) {
        case ROOT_MENU: 
            page_RootMenu(); 
            break;
        case RTC_SETUP: 
            page_RtcSetup(); 
            break;
        // Add other cases for other menu pages if needed
    }

    // Other code or logic can be added here

    // Keep a specific pace (optional) to avoid rapid menu changes or excessive processing
    // You can adjust the delay time based on your needs
    delay(500);
}
```

I want to print running rtc values on lcd display and when pressing the Button accept i want to access to the menu.from menu i can setup rtc values.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the line

```
displayRTCValues();
```

it's in the wrong place and needs to be a part of the switch statement or using a variable to track if you are in a menu or not, otherwise your program flow's like this:

1. displayRTCValues(); //clear the screen and show the time
2. check if the button is pressed and then show some menu page
3. wait for 500ms
4. loop restarts and the displayRTCValues() probably clears the screen so effectively you only see your menu page for 500ms

It should be more like this

1. treat your showing of the clock as another page (i.e. homePage)
2. use the button clicks to show whatever page it needs - that's where you clear() the screen and draw your page
3. don't clear the screen as a part of the loop()

This is a quick and dirty example assuming only one button that scrolls through different pages and when it reaches the end goes back to some homepage with the clock

```
int currentPage = 1; //just a simple way referencing pages by numbers
int maxPages = 3; 

//stick all the time reading and showing as a separate function
void page_HomePage(){
      t = rtc.getTime();// print the current time on display
      Day = rtc.getDOWStr(1);//Print the name of the day on display

      hh = t.hour,DEC;
      mm = t.min,DEC;
      ss = t.sec,DEC;
      dd = t.date,DEC;
      bb = t.mon,DEC;
      y = t.year,DEC;

      displayRTCValues();
}

void loop(){

   if (btnIsUp(BTN_ACCEPT) && !btn_Accept_WasDown) {
        //inside this if statement is where you implement your logic not outside

        while (btnIsUp(BTN_ACCEPT)) {
            delay(50);
        }
        
        currentPage++;

        if(currentPage > maxPage){ // we've scrolled to the end
           currentPage = 1; //go back to the home page
        }

        

        // Clear the LCD display - optional here, probably better if every page does it's own clear and draw of the screen
        lcd.clear();

        switch (currentPage) {
          case 1: 
            page_HomePage();

           break;
         case 2: 
       
           page_RootMenu(); 
           break;

         case 3: 
            page_RtcSetup(); 
          
           break;
       }

  }

}
```

This is just a rough illustration, hopefully it gives you some idea

Comment: Thank for your repply sir.i will try under your guilines. if u can, check my whole code i can upload it for u sir.good day..

Comment: Sure, I can have a quick look at your code and give you some directions but this is not a place for that. I have a small support forum on my private site, it’s currently empty but you can contact me there. The link is in my profile.

Comment: sure no matter.....